# bilinear equation OR diagonal matrix search

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Having a real square $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $B$ (which consists of 2 square blocks of positive numbers and 2 rectangular blocks of negative numbers)  I want a real diagonal matrix $D$ such that column vector of $n$ $1$'s ("ones(n,1)" in matlab syntax) is an eigenvector of $DBD$.

In other words I want a vector $d$ for which $\sum_{j=1}^n B_{ij} d_i d_j = 1$ for $i=1..n$ ($B_{ij}$ are elements of the same matrix $B$)

Any deterministic (polynomial in time) way to result

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/robert.reams/research/sinkhorn.pdf) gives an algorithm on page $4$. Since the algorithm is iterative, I suspect that no exact algorithm is known (which I assume is what you meant by "deterministic (polynomial in time)").